# javascript slider change call function sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following are some code for explaining

```
$("#upperBound").on('input',function(){
                console.log("1");
                loadAndViewImagethresholding(imageId);
                console.log("4");   
            });

function loadAndViewImagethresholding(imageId) {
        _("thresholdingdicomImage").style.opacity = "0.3";
         var elementthresh = $('#thresholdingdicomImage').get(0);

        cornerstone.enable(elementthresh);

        var imageIdpro="wadouri:"+"http://localhost:8888/dicomread/temp/"+loadfileName;

        cornerstone.loadImage(imageId).then(function(image) {
            cornerstone.loadImage(imageIdpro).then(function(imagepro) {
            upper=_("upperBound").value;
            lower=_("lowerBound").value;
            for (var i = 0;i<image.getPixelData().length;i++) {
                if(imagepro.getPixelData()[i]<lower||imagepro.getPixelData()[i]>upper)
                {  
                    imagepro.getPixelData()[i]=image.minPixelValue;
                //    console.log("imageproCopyaftercompare:"+imagepro.getPixelData()[436512]);
                }
                else{imagepro.getPixelData()[i]=image.maxPixelValue;
                    //console.log("imageproCopyaftercompare:"+imagepro.getPixelData()[436512]); 
                }
            }
            console.log("imageproCopyaftercompare:"+imagepro.getPixelData()[436512]);
            var viewportthresh = cornerstone.getDefaultViewportForImage(elementthresh, imagepro);
            console.log("2");
            cornerstone.displayImage(elementthresh, imagepro);
        });
      });  
    }
```

So the basic idea is to use slide`upperBound` to change upper (lower) value to threshold image, but it seems nothing changed after I change slider. I make a `console.log` for 436512th pixel, It seems after give slider input that `imagepro`(which is a raw data array) has been changed, but next displayImage is not implemented.

Then I make a `console.log("1 to 4")` to see how that slider event implement, the result is 1,4,2,3 rather than 1,2,3,4 as I expect.

So my question is how does this slider implement? Will it implements 1,4 first then calling the function(loadAndViewImagethresholding(imageId);) inside?

If possible, give me some idea to fix that problem, any help appreciated.
BTW, cornerstone is the js I used.

Comment: Since image loading is an asynchronous operation if you put a code `cornerstone.loadImage` it's asynchronous operation so it will not wait for image to load so that's why the sequence is 1,4,2,3

Comment: @Curiousdev it is possible to make it to be synchronous, in other word, implement is order? Coz what I expect is when slider changes call image to load and display, thank you for your response